# If $Y$ is a closed and bounded subset of an ordered space $X$ then is it compact?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, order-theory, well-orders

Let be $(X,\preccurlyeq)$ a totally ordered set. So if $Y$ is a bounded and closed subset of $X$ with respect the order topology then is it compact? if this is not generally true then is it true when $X$ has maximum of minimum?

Anyway it seem to that the statement is true when $X$ is a well ordered set with a minimum $m$ and maximum $M$ element, that is a well ordered space is compact.

> Indeed if $\mathcal U$ is an open cover of $X$ then  ther exist $U_0\in\mathcal U$ such that $$M\in U_0$$ However $U_0$ is a neighborhood of $M$ so that there must exist a basic neighrbohood of $M$ there contained, that is there must exist $x_0\in X$ such that $$(x_0,M]\subseteq U_0$$ Now if $\mathcal U$ cover $X$ then there exists $U_1\in\mathcal U$ such that $$x_0\in U_1$$ However $U_1$ is a neighrborhood of $x_0$ so that there must exist a basic neighrbohood of $x_0$ there contained, that is there must exist $x_1\in X$ such that $$(x_1,x_0]\subseteq U_1$$
> So in this way we can define a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\omega}$ in $X$ which has surely a minimum element and it seem to me that this element must be $m$ so that there exist $n\in\omega$ such that $x_n$ is $m$ and thus finally $U_0,\dots, U_n$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal U$.

Anyway I point out that this do not prove that $Y$ is compact because the subspece topology of $X$ on $Y$ is not generally equal to the ordered topology on $Y$.

So could you explain why $m$ is the minimum of the above sequece? Moreover could you show is the statement is true also when $X$ is not well ordered, please?

Comment: @freakish He means bounded with respect to the given order relation $\preceq$ on $X$.

Comment: @freakish As Meander suggested $Y$ is bounded if and only if there exists $y_m,y_M\in X$ such that the inequlity $$y_m\preccurlyeq y\preccurlyeq y_M$$ hods for any $y\in Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X = [0,1) \cup (2,3]$ endowed with the usual order relation defined on $\mathbb{R}$. In the order topology, $[0,1)$ is a closed and bounded subset of $X$ that is not compact. In general, if $(X, \preceq)$ is a totally ordered set *with the least upper bound property*, then closed and bounded subsets of $X$ are compact in the order topology. But the space $X$ that I have defined here clearly does not have the least upper bound property, hence the counterexample. See Theorem 27.1 in Munkres for a proof of the statement about the least upper bound criterion.

Comment: Okay, so could you say if I can argue that the statement is true for well ordered set by the upper bound criterion?

Comment: I saw Theorem 27.1 in Munkres: however it proves only the statement for closed interval so that why the result holds also for not closed intervals? could you explain, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Every well-ordered set has the least upper bound property.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro If a subset of $X$ is bounded, then it is contained in a closed and bounded interval. A closed subset of a compact set is compact.

Comment: @freakish Howewer  the last Menanderl comment is true, right? Whereas I do not know if every well-ordered set has the least upper bound property, e.g. take $\omega$.

Comment: @freakish Many thanks for spotting my error! I have edited my reply accordingly.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro well, a **bounded** subset of a well ordered set does have the least upper bound property: it is the smallest among upper bounds (which exists because of well ordering). Also I've delete my answer, because the example I gave actually was not closed. This here seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: @freakish Okay, however I think that a well ordered set is compact: indeed it the counterexample you deleted show only that $Y$ can be not compact, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro No, a well ordered set is compact if and only if it is a non-limit ordinal. Think about naturals $\omega$.

Comment: @freakish Oh, sorry: "obviously" I wanted mean a well ordered set with maximum and minimum!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro every well ordered set has the smallest element btw. But yes, being a non-limit ordinal is equivalent to having the greatest element. And that's why my example failed: because a closed subset of non-limit ordinal has to be compact.

Comment: @freakich Okay, thanks.

Comment: @MenanderI Thanks for your answer.